# Why is stencil buffer not working after page reload on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, webgl, browser-cache, stencil-buffer

Are there any clues about the reason why the following website fails to color continents after **page reload** on Chrome?

http://opensciencemap.org/map/

Some clues:

1. No problem with page reloads on Firefox and Safari.
2. No problem with page reloads on on Incognito mode @ Chrome.
3. No problem on new tab @ Chrome.

Success:
[image: Succeeded]

Failure:
[image: Failed]

Comment: Any errors? What makes you believe its stencil buffer related ?

Comment: No errors(!). Watching http://opensciencemap.org/map/#&scale=14&rot=0&tilt=0&lat=40.722&lon=-74.047, Failure image: http://imgur.com/GLodcpA , Success image: http://imgur.com/7dE91MM . You can see that the maps are colored per "tile". I guessed it's stencil buffer related because the (wrongly drawn) colors seems to be used to draw some kind of geometry on each tile with stencil, but since stencil isn't working it drew all over the tile.

Comment: Found out there are no problems on windows version... only on OSX and Linux.

Comment: I am unable to repo. I'm on OSX 10.11.6 on a mid 2015 Macbook Pro, Chrome 52. Try disabling your extensions?

Comment: Same here, working fine on Linux(Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS), Intel HD 4000 and Chrome 51.0.2704.106